# Unable to Connect to PostgreSQL from psycopg2 - OperationalError: FATAL: role "victoryhb" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu and I used the following command to install PostgreSQL

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4 pgadmin3
```

It seems the installation was successful, the PostgreSQL service is listening on port 5432, and I can interact with the PG server using *psql* under the *postgres* user account.
But now when I tried to connect PG from Python using psycopg2:

```
psycopg2.connect(database="mydb", user="postgres")
```

I encountered the following error:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

despite the fact that the role "postgres" already exists as confirmed by typing the "\du" command in *psql*.

Any hint what might have caused this strange problem?

P.S.

- Before connecting, I also had to apply "ln -s
     /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" following the
     advice from
     https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432
- It doesn't seem to be the problem of psycopg2 since I also
     tested with another library pg8000 and got the same "role postgres
     does not exist" error

Comment: Possibly set a password for the postgres user?

Comment: @hd1 Thanks but I tried: ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'abc123'; in psql but didn't solve the problem. :(